# Передать массив из PHP в JavaScript Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста передать из PHP массив в JS. Вот код. P.S В столбце Idperson содержатся числа.
Server.php

```js
<?php
$dbName = 'qwerty';
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'qwerty') ;
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli,$dbName);
    $data = array();
    $select_sql = ('SELECT Idperson FROM test');
 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$select_sql);
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $data= json_encode( $row);
?>
```

Принимаю на стороне JS вот так:

```js
<script>
var mass=[];
$.ajax({
    url:'server.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
        if(data){
           console.log(data); 
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что мне надо теперь правильно принять на стороне JS и засунуть в массив mass. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы не сможете засунуть в массив `mass` из вашего примера данные, т.к. AJAX - это асинхронный процесс. Вы должны поместить ваш массив внутрь коллбека `success` и работать с этими данными в дальнейшем внутри именно этого коллбека. Короче говоря, добро пожаловать в клуб разработчиков JavaScript, где любят пожестче.

Comment: А как правильно в коллбеке обработать приходящий массив? У меня просто в дата ничего не записывается сейчас

Comment: Ну так вы в примере на PHP в цикле каждый раз перезаписываете переменную `$data` JSON-строкой. Вам надо сначала "накапливать" данные в массиве, который вы должны инициализировать вне цикла, а затем эти "накопленные" данные сконвертировать в JSON и отдать через `echo`. После этого переменная `data` в вашем JavaScript будет рабочей. С AJAX-запросом у вас, в принципе, все в порядке. Проблема в PHP.

Comment: Не мог бы в примере показать? 30 минут сижу мучаюсь не могу сделать... буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

А чем плох этот подход:

```
var mass=[];
...
success: function(data){
  mass = data.slice(0);
}
...
```

Правда копировать ответ куда-то - это странно. Модифицируйте его, а результаты можете хранить где-то.

Comment: why 1? Чем не угодил первый элемент массива? =)

Comment: @vp_arth пришёл первым к финишу? нет - нулевым!

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно собрать строки в массив, просто соберите строки в массив:

```
$data[] = $row;
```

А результат уже можно заjsonить после цикла:

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Отдаётся json обычно как-то так:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit;
```